# Difficulty joining two MySQL tables with out guaranteed ID match

Tags: php, mysql

I have a complex situation that I have been trying to figure out on joining two tables. The basic structure is that I have table `S` that contains name, num, box, and user and table `D` that contains the same 4 fields, name, num, box and user.

I can match box and user easily enough, but its not quite enough.  I also need to match name when possible.

### S

```
Dave,1234,3,jon
Scot,1111,3,jon
Bill,4389,3,abe
```

### D

```
Mark,3333,3,jon
Dave,3355,3,jon
Lime,9832,6,jon
```

What i need for the result would like this

```
Dave,1234,3355,3,jon
Scot,1111,null,3,jon
Mark,null,3333,3,jon
```

I've tried a couple different join types, but the problem is that the tables dont have IDs that line up and the name is possible to exist in both but isnt required.  When it does exist in both I want the num for both, but only a single name.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up, you beat me to it by a few seconds.

Comment: so how does it work if the name AND id don't match?

Comment: the username and board should always match, the name should always show in one table or both, and each table will only have its own num

Answer (score 0):

First, I would say that DB design needs work.

But if you are unable to change the design, I think a full outer join on the nave variable will give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for the data that you have provided. I am not sure if there is more than this in the data:.

```
select s.name, s.num, d.num, s.box, s.user from s, d where s.name = d.name
union
select s.name, s.num, "null", s.box, s.user from s where s.name not in (select s.name from s, d where s.name = d.name)
union 
select d.name, "null",d.num, d.box, d.user from d where d.name not in (select s.name from s, d where s.name = d.name)
```

Check the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e7363/13) here.

Comment: This is very close to what i need, the onlything im having trouble with now is adding in the WHEREs to check that the user and box are for the user and box that i need the data for.

Answer (score 0):

Getting some assistance from another source, I was able to expand upon the answer that Prerak supplied and came up with the following using a subquery that contained the unions

```
select * from (
select s.name, s.num as sNum, d.num as dNum, s.board, s.username from s, d where s.name = d.name
union
select s.name, s.num as sNum, "null", s.board, s.username from s where s.name not in (select s.name from s, d where s.name = d.name)
union
select d.name, "null",d.num as dNum, d.board, d.username from d where d.name not in (select s.name from s, d where s.name = d.name)
) as dataTab
where user = 'jon' and box = 3
```